# How to set a group's entire column from a conditional evaluation of one of its rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tsibble with data for a month's worth of days, for all years, like:

```
# A tsibble: 45 x 8 [1D]
     day monthNo  year monthName close date       closePct 
   <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <ord>     <dbl> <date>        <dbl>
 1     1       8  1928 August     19.4 1928-08-01    0    
 2     2       8  1928 August     19.3 1928-08-02   -0.463  
 3     3       8  1928 August     19.4 1928-08-03   -0.309  
 4     6       8  1928 August     19.6 1928-08-06    0.824  
 5     7       8  1928 August     19.5 1928-08-07    0.360
```

from which I draw a spaghetti chart using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=day, y=closePct, group=year, color=year)) +
  geom_line()
```

I would like to gray out the lines in the chart where closePct values on a specific day, or the next actual day in the table if that one's not present, don't fall in a specific range.

I think I can do this by adding something like a "isMatch" column and adding an aes(alpha=isMatch) parameter but I'm unclear how to:

1. Fill in an entire group's column value for isMatch when the closePct range matches (something like mutate(isMatch = (closePct>minValue && closePct<maxValue)), but propagated to the entire group), and
2. Combine this with finding the valid date to test (min(day) <= dayToTest)

all whilst writing normal R vector code.

Or is this too difficult and should I process it procedurally?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work, so I'm adding it here.

I'm far from convinced however that it's a good solution.  Any suggestions warmly welcomed.

```
x = wkmoData %>%
  filter( monthNo == monthNoToPlot ) %>%
  filter( year >= firstYear, year <= lastYear  ) %>%
  select( c("day", "monthNo", "year", "monthName", "close") ) %>%
  group_by( year ) %>%
  mutate( closePct = (close - first(close)) / first(close)* 100 ) %>%       # pct change since start of month
  mutate( actualTestDay = min(replace(day, day < nominalDayToTest, NA), na.rm=TRUE) ) %>%    # find first day on or after target date
  #mutate(isMatch = ifelse(day == actualTestDay & closePct > minValueToTest , TRUE, FALSE)) %>%    # && short-circuit does NOT work here
  mutate(isMatch = ifelse(day == actualTestDay, ifelse(closePct > minValueToTest & closePct < maxValueToTest, TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)) %>% # do it the hard way
  mutate(isMatch = any(isMatch, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%    # propagate to column 
  ungroup() 
 
  

ggplot(x, aes(x=day, y=closePct, group=year, color=year, alpha=isMatch)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("TRUE"=1, "FALSE"=0.1), guide = "none") +
  aes(colour = factor(year)) +
  guides(colour="none")
```